# IndexError: cannot choose from an emty sequence

Tags: python

I'm trying to get random numbers from a list, but the numbers are only allowed to go up from the first number that was randomly chosen. It works fine the first time it loops but on the second loop it gives this errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): Num = random.choice(listNum)
```

and:

```
raise IndexError('Cannot choose from an empty sequence')
```

This is the code I use:

```
import random

listNum = list(range(100))

for n in range(100):
    Num = random.choice(listNum)
    print(Num)
    del listNum[0:Num]
    print(listNum)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Could you post the output of your script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
del listNum[0:Num]
```

you delete all elements up to the index Num, except that after the first loop it's not doing exactly what you want, because it doesn't delete up to Num, but deletes Num elements, what you want is :

```
del listNum[0:listNum.index(Num)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `try` `except`, it will catch index error, and do stuff that will help you solve that error

```
for n in range(100):
    try:
        Num = random.choice(listNum)
        print(Num)
        del listNum[0:Num]
        print(listNum)
    except IndexError:  # this will handle only IndexError, don't use pure except
        break  # stop loop when there are no more numbers
```

some other smarter solutions would be:

```
while len(listNum):
   # do same stuff here
   # print number only when list has at least 1 element
```

also, remeber that your list is getting smaller, so you can not just `del [0: Num]`